# Generating problem text automatically

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, syntax

I want to randomly generate groups of radom parabolas to be graphed as follows:

#### Graphing — Parabolas

$\qquad f(x) = a\, x ^ 2$ (3 of them)
$\qquad f(x) = a\, x ^ 2 + b\, x$ (3 of them)
$\qquad f(x) = a\, x ^ 2 + b\, x + c$ (3 of them)

I want to export each group (9 in total) to a PDF file (letter).

```
sig := 2 * Random[Integer, {0, 1}] - 1;
a := Random[Integer, {1, 9}];
b := Random[Integer, {-9, 9}];
c := Random[Integer, {-9, 9}]
nul := Random[Integer, {0, 1}] - 1;

For [i = 0, i < 9, i++,
  Print["f(x) = ", sig*a, "x^2", nul*sig * b, "x ", nul*sig*c]]
```

This is very poor, but I'm just starting to help.

Answer (score 2):

There are a ton of ways to do this, but I'll try to do it in a way that makes sense to somebody newer.

First, a couple of things:

- Mathematica has a function called `RandomInteger`, so you can use that. The syntax is `RandomInteger[{start,end},n]`, where `n` is the number of random integers you want between `start` and `end`.
- When you can, avoid loops. There's usually a better way to do it, often with `Map` (shorthand `/@`).

In this case, using `ReplaceAll` (shorthand `/.`) is a reasonable way to go. We have a general form of a quadratic polynomial, `a x^2 + b x + c`, and we want to replace the constants with either random numbers or 0.

`a x^2 + b x + c /.{a->1,b->2,c->3}`

would generate:

`1 x^2 + 2 x + 3`

for example.

Basically, we're just going to feed it three random numbers, and two zeros. Then, two sets of random numbers and one zero. Lastly, three sets of random numbers. Mathematica intelligently threads over the lists.

`a x^2 + b x + c /. {
{a -> RandomInteger[{1, 9}, 3], b -> 0, 
   c -> 0}, 
{a -> RandomInteger[{1, 9}, 3], 
   b -> RandomInteger[{1, 9}, 3], c -> 0},
{a -> RandomInteger[{1, 9}, 3], b -> RandomInteger[{1, 9}, 3], 
   c -> RandomInteger[{1, 9}, 3]}}`

running this once gives:

`{{8 x^2, 9 x^2, 8 x^2}, {5 x + 5 x^2, 3 x + 5 x^2, 
  4 x + 7 x^2}, {2 + 2 x + 4 x^2, 5 + 8 x + 7 x^2, 2 + 8 x + x^2}}`

We can pretty it up with `GridBox` and some options: wrap the whole thing with:

`DisplayForm@GridBox[ ... , GridBoxDividers -> {"Rows" -> {{True}}, "Columns" -> {{True}}}]`

and you'll get something like:

[image]

Now, if you want `n` of these, you can just throw that whole thing in a `Table[...,{n}]`, so:

`quadGrids = Table[DisplayForm@GridBox[... ],{n}]`

Now you have `n` grids of 9 quadratic polynomials satisfying the conditions you wanted. All that's left is to export them. I'm pretty sleepy, so I won't go through this in detail now, but use this:

`MapIndexed[
 Export["quadGrid" <> ToString@#2[[1]] <> ".pdf", #1] &, quadGrids]`

and you'll get what you want (it doesn't matter how many you made; it'll export them all and number them all automatically). The idea is that it grabs each thing in the list of grids, then exports it with a number corresponding to its place in that list.

Feel free to let me know if there's anything here that you'd like clarification on, if there's anything else you'd like to implement, or if i've misunderstood anything!

Comment: Thanks for your help, your code served me in part
I need a, b and c to take negative values, but I do not know how to exclude zero, I attach an idea of what I need

[ dropbox.com/sh/9vlajdta56014fs/AACaaLcEyhDhjdWux-4mrnOEa?dl=‌​0]


a -> RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, 3] How do I exclude zero here?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t3ukukbjj5qdfhy/quadGrid1.pdf?dl=0

Comment: If you replace all of the `RandomInteger` bits with `RandomChoice[Range[-9,9]/.0->Nothing,3]`, I think it should work the same. I'm not at my computer to check right now, but let me know.

Comment: hanks for the information